# how do i make changes while assigning in q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

For example, I know that:

```
c1 xasc table
```

Will return a table that is sorted in ascending order by values in `c1`, but that does not change the table itself. So i wonder if there exist a method other than

```
table:`c1 xasc table
```

that can apply the change to the table.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:r], the statistical programming language. This doesn't look like R code.  Please tag this correctly.

Comment: @rekire I have no idea. This is what Wikipedia says: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(programming_language_from_Kx_Systems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following, which overwrites the old table with the new sorted version.

```
`c1 xasc `table
```

Comment: Beware that this will not work on local variables inside a function. In that instance you will need to assign back to the original variable, as you demonstrated in your question.